# Views, Partials and Layouts in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

A RESTful API means you can go to `/posts` and get a list of all posts, and go to `/posts/:id` to get a specific post.
So I have a view called `index` for `/posts` and a view `show` for `/posts/:id`.

Seeing as the `/posts` is a list of posts, I'd like to just use the `show` view inside the `index` view to same me having the same HTML twice. But the `show` view is not a Partial view because it has it's own controller so how can I include it in `index`?

Also to add to this confusion, I don't understand why there are Views and Layouts? What situation would you need to use a Layout and not a View?

Comment: The *layout* is the wrapper for the page content. The SE black bar, SO header, right sidebar, and footer on this page would be the layout; then the view would handle the question and answer inside that. Or, on a question listing, the view would handle the question list.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a partial to display an individual post and invoke that partial from both your `show` and `index` controller methods.

Layouts are view elements intended to be shared across other "primary" view elements.

Answer (score 1):

Layout is nothing but wrapper to your view content.
It is also used to maintain same look and feel across the website.
One of the purpose of Layout is to reduce redundancy i.e. DRY.

If you want to use show view code in index view,
you need to modify your show view, move all your code of show view to a partial and call that partial in show by passing your resource as local.
And you can use the same partial in index.